# Append xml nodes to another xml using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to append the nodes of an xml to another xml using jquery ? Find the requirement below.

First XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
  <First>
   <a>a</a>
   <b>b</b>
  </First>
</Root>
```

Second XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Root>
  <Test>
   <a>aa</a>
   <b>bb</b>
  </Test>
   <Test>
   <a>aaa</a>
   <b>bbb</b>
  </Test>
</Root>
```

Expected

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <Root>
      <First>
       <a>a</a>
       <b>b</b>
      </First>
      <Test>
       <a>aa</a>
       <b>bb</b>
      </Test>
       <Test>
       <a>aaa</a>
       <b>bbb</b>
      </Test>
    </Root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('Root:first').children().prependTo($('Root:eq(1)'));
$('Root:first').remove();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NDXx8/2)

Comment: i have the first and second xml in a variable than how can i write the above code ?

Comment: @Pradeep Can you post that variables?